# Drag rows in order in a table python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I have a html like this

Link to html

http://threedonthemap.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Easy Drag and Drop HTML Table Rows With jQuery</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <main role="main" class="container">

     <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Jabcode</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>01</td>
              <td>E24.9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>02</td>
              <td>J92.9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>03</td>
              <td>A10.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>04</td>
              <td>B10.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>05</td>
              <td>C4.9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>06</td>
              <td>D10.11</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>07</td>
              <td>F19.10</td>             
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    </main><!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Bootstrap & Core Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('tbody').sortable();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Which currently has the particular order in webpage

[image]

I want to change the order of the items in the webpage based on parameters I give in my python program.

Here is my python code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
import time 

jab_code_order =['J92.9','A10.2','E24.9','B10.2','F19.10','D10.11','C4.9']
    # browser = 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/chromedrivernew')
driver.get("file:////datasets/demodragable/index.html")





for item in jab_code_order:
    cell=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='ui-sortable-handle']//td[text()='"+ item + "']")
    print(cell.text)
    source_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='ui-sortable-handle']//td[text()='"+ item + "']")
    dest_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='ui-sortable-handle']//td[text()='A10.2']")
    ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(source_element, dest_element).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
```

With the current code it is coming like this

[image]

I want the table order like this

[image]

Is there any pythonic way of doing it rather than looping through ?

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this an interview question lol? You got some more for me?

Here is the issue, `drag_and_drop` on this page only works when your desired destination is below your source. I used `drag_and_drop_by_offset` to fix this and add 5 pixels.  See the documentation here (https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) Also remember that every time you move an element the order of the list has been changed.  I added a new function to find all the elements on that page for each iteration of the loop to solve that issue.
See below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
import time 

jab_code_order =['J92.9','A10.2','E24.9','B10.2','F19.10','D10.11','C4.9']
    # browser = 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Path\\To\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("file://C:\\Path\\To\\index.html")


def get_current_element_order():
    array_of_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody//tr")
    return array_of_elements

for item in range(len(jab_code_order)):
    cell=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='ui-sortable-handle']//td[text()='"+ jab_code_order[item] + "']")
    print(cell.text)
    source_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='ui-sortable-handle']//td[text()='"+ jab_code_order[item] + "']")
    current_order_of_elements = get_current_element_order()
    dest_element = current_order_of_elements[item]
    if dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y'] < 0:
        ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(source_element,
                                                     0,
                                                     dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y'] - 5).perform()
    else:
        ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(source_element,
                                                     0,
                                                     dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y']).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Glad to help, remember the documentation is your friend.  https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html

Comment: can you please see the changes I have made to the file path ?

Comment: @user9538877 I think there are too many slashes in that file path `file:////index.html`.

Comment: Do: `local_file = "C:\\Path\\To\\local\\index.html"` then `driver.get('file://' + local_file)`

Comment: in the same senerio instead of the jabcode how can we move the element by id ?

Comment: What if you can drag it only by ID column ?

Comment: Was wondering in the table if the only id column is drag-able

Comment: How are you calculating the offset ?

Comment: How to get the offset dynamically ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615492/drag-by-specific-column-sort-the-table-python-selenium

Comment: I could not figure it out

Comment: @user9538877 The function `get_current_element_order()` is helping with the dynamic offset.  If I solve this next one for you it will hinder you from learning.... Here's how to start. Write a script to only drag one element to the correct location.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I have been struggling on this since two days

Comment: I tired to get the offset dynamically but the click is happening on the Jabcode

Comment: It would be a lot helpful if you can show me a way out !