# Drag by specific column sort the table python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a html like this

Link to html

http://fileuploadios.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

```
<style type="text/css">
                body {
              font-size: 14px;
            }

            .drag-handler {
              width: 8em;
              position: relative;
              background-color: #E4E6EB;
              background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #E4E6EB, #E4E6EB 2px, #fff 2px, #fff 4px, #E4E6EB 4px, #E4E6EB 9px, #fff 9px, #fff 11px, #E4E6EB 11px, #E4E6EB 16px, #fff 16px, #fff 18px, #E4E6EB 18px, #E4E6EB 22px);
              background-size: 10px 20px;
              cursor: move;
              border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
              border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
            }

            .drag-handler:active {
              background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #bab86c, #bab86c 2px, #fff 2px, #fff 4px, #bab86c 4px, #bab86c 9px, #fff 9px, #fff 11px, #bab86c 11px, #bab86c 16px, #fff 16px, #fff 18px, #bab86c 18px, #bab86c 22px);
              background-size: 10px 20px;
            }

</style>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Drag Button
      </th>
      <th>
        Number
      </th>
      <th>
        Jabcode
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="sortable">
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>1</td>
        <td>E24.9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>2</td>
              <td>J92.9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>3</td>
              <td>A10.2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>4</td>
              <td>B10.2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>5</td>
              <td>C4.9</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>6</td>
              <td>D10.11</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>7</td>
              <td>F19.10</td>             
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Z20.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#sortable").sortable({
    handle: ".drag-handler"
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();

});

</script>
```

Which is in the following Way

[image]

I want to rearrange this based on the Jabcode in my python program

```
jab_code_order =['J92.9','A10.2','E24.9','B10.2','F19.10','D10.11']
```

This is my python code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
import time 

jab_code_order =['J92.9','A10.2','E24.9','B10.2','F19.10','D10.11']
lis = ["1","2","3",]



driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedrivernew')
driver.get("file:////newhtml.html")

time.sleep(5)


def get_current_element_order():
    array_of_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody//tr")
    return array_of_elements

for item in range(len(jab_code_order)):
    cell=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='ui-sortable-handle']//td[text()='"+ jab_code_order[item] + "']")
    # print(cell.text)
    source_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@class='ui-sortable-handle']//td[text()='"+ jab_code_order[item] + "']")
    current_order_of_elements = get_current_element_order()
    dest_element = current_order_of_elements[item]
    # print(dest_element)
    # children = source_element.find_elements_by_xpath('./*')
    # print(children)


    if dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y'] < 0:
        # print(dest_element.location['y'])
        print("if")
        print(source_element,0,dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y'] - 1)

        ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(source_element,
                                                     0,
                                                     dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y'] - 5).perform()
    else:
        print("else")
        ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(source_element,
                                                     0,
                                                     dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y']).perform()
    time.sleep(2)
```

I want output like this

[image]

But my current code fails to do that it tries to go the Jabcode and tries to drag. Based on the jabcode how to drag the element in the table from the first child in the tr ?

Help would be appreciated !!
Thanks+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the challenge here is finding a way to map the button element to the element with the text found in the variable `jab_code_order`.

I added a few "helper functions" that execute each time to get the order of the new list. Maybe not the most "programmiclly efficient" but works.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Path\\To\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('file://C:\Path\\To\\newhtml.html')

time.sleep(2)


jab_code_order =['J92.9','A10.2','E24.9','B10.2','F19.10','D10.11']
lis = ["1","2","3",]

def get_current_element_order():
    array_of_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody//tr")
    return array_of_elements

def map_text_lcation():
    text_array_to_return = []
    for element in get_current_element_order():
        text_array_to_return.append(element.text)
    return text_array_to_return


def get_current_button_order():
    get_current_button_order_dict = {}
    for iii in range(len(map_text_lcation())):
        for ii in get_current_element_order():
            a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tbody tr:nth-child({})".format(iii + 1))
            if ii.text == a.text:
                get_current_button_order_dict[ii.text] = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tbody tr:nth-child({}) td:nth-child(1)".format(iii + 1))
    return get_current_button_order_dict

for item in range(len(jab_code_order)):
    element_dict = get_current_button_order()
    this_key = ""
    for key in element_dict:
        if jab_code_order[item] in key:
            this_key = key
    source_element = element_dict[this_key]
    current_order_of_elements = get_current_element_order()
    dest_element = current_order_of_elements[item]

    if dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y'] < 0:
        print("if")
        print(source_element,0,dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y'] - 1)

        ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(source_element,
                                                     0,
                                                     dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y'] - 5).perform()
    else:
        print("else")
        ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(source_element,
                                                     0,
                                                     dest_element.location['y'] - source_element.location['y']).perform()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)")))
```

Comment: Great answer. Perhaps replacing `time.sleep(2)` with _WebDriverWait_ will make it flawless.