# Arrange rows Of A Table Sikuli Dynamically

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

I have a html page like this

```
<style type="text/css">
                body {
              font-size: 14px;
            }

            .drag-handler {
              width: 8em;
              position: relative;
              background-color: #E4E6EB;
              background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #E4E6EB, #E4E6EB 2px, #fff 2px, #fff 4px, #E4E6EB 4px, #E4E6EB 9px, #fff 9px, #fff 11px, #E4E6EB 11px, #E4E6EB 16px, #fff 16px, #fff 18px, #E4E6EB 18px, #E4E6EB 22px);
              background-size: 10px 20px;
              cursor: move;
              border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
              border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
            }

            .drag-handler:active {
              background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #bab86c, #bab86c 2px, #fff 2px, #fff 4px, #bab86c 4px, #bab86c 9px, #fff 9px, #fff 11px, #bab86c 11px, #bab86c 16px, #fff 16px, #fff 18px, #bab86c 18px, #bab86c 22px);
              background-size: 10px 20px;
            }

</style>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Drag Button
      </th>
      <th>
        Number
      </th>
      <th>
        Jabcode
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="sortable">
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>1</td>
        <td>E24.9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>2</td>
              <td>J92.9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>3</td>
              <td>A10.2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>4</td>
              <td>B10.2</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>5</td>
              <td>C4.9</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>6</td>
              <td>D10.11</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>7</td>
              <td>F19.10</td>             
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td class="ui-state-default drag-handler" ></td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Z20.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#sortable").sortable({
    handle: ".drag-handler"
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();

});

</script>
```

I want to arrange rows dynamically is there any way to do it in sikuli ? I have achieved using selenium but is there any way to do it with out selenium ?

Link to my selenium problem :- [Drag by specific column sort the table python selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615492/drag-by-specific-column-sort-the-table-python-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can reorder rows
https://www.screencast.com/t/2SmZ9lSz

Code shows how to found all buttons and move them on the first place.(by default list is not ordered)

How you can extend this:
You can sort received list by Y and then you can manipulate individual items by their visible order